# In what sense, does a safe register exist?

Tags: dc.distributed-comp, concurrency, ar.hardware-architecture

In the paper ["On Interprocess Communication"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/interprocess.pdf), the author Leslie Lamport have developed a formalism for interprocess communication via shared registers based on lower-level, *non-atomic* operations and have proposed the definitions of *safe, regular, and atomic* registers. [Also Lamport's description for the "interprocess" publication.](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/pubs.html#interprocess)

For *safe* registers, a read that overlaps a write operation is allowed to return *any* one of the possible values of the register.

My problem is

> How practically relevant is this specification of *safe* registers?

Particularly, is it possible for a read of an *actual register/memory unit* in a multiprocessor computer to return an arbitrary value when it is concurrent with a write?

What about going to a lower level such as circuits/flip-flop?

In what sense, does a *safe* register exist?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence — you do not read & write the same **physical** register simultaneously, however, you may read & write cached copies of the value in different local caches, and then it is up to the **cache coherence protocol** what might happen. Usually, the low-level details are not visible to the programmer; the contract between the programmer and the underlying system is the **memory model**, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)

Comment: Oh, I just realised that there are certain systems in which simultaneous read & write on a physical level might be indeed possible: dual-port RAM. For example, this might be relevant: http://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/129836-ac374-simultaneous-read-write-operations-in-dual-port-sram-for-flash-based-csocs-and-fpgas-app-note

Comment: @JukkaSuomela Thanks. The "dual-port RAM" article is helpful. Would you mind converting your comment to an answer?

Comment: Let's wait and see if someone who knows a bit more about the topic writes an answer. :)  I think you might also consider asking at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ where there are people who actually understand the low-level hardware details much better.